# Table Row Selected Colour Change JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

I am trying to change the **blue border colour** when the **row** is selected. How can I change this colour?

[image]

Comment: Please share some code what you are tried.......

Comment: What are you using vanilla JavaFx or FXML to build your UI?

Comment: @cdaiga I am using Vanilla JavaFX, CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {

    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;

}
```

Comment: @Anfuca, this property doesn't exist in JavaFX CSS Reference Guild on Oracle's site. Can you tell me where on Earth i can a complete reference that lists all properties?